# SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out, how to fix it?

Tags: java, swing, sockets, exception

I have a swing application that read HTML pages using the following command

```
String urlzip = null;
try {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
        for (Element link : links) {
            if (link.attr("abs:href").contains("BcfiHtm.zip")) {
                urlzip = link.attr("abs:href").toString();
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        textAreaStatus.append("Failed to get new file from internet:"+e.getMessage()+"\n");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
return urlzip;
```

then my swing application will return a string, It works fine and it reads any HTML page that I give to it. However, some times  the application gave me the following error type Exception report. How can i increase timeOut?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's an example on [this page](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/input/load-document-from-url).

```
Jsoup.connect("http://example.com").timeout(3000)
```

Answer (score 3):

This error occurs while you are trying to read data and because of large data or connection problem it can not complete the task. I would suggest you to increase your Timeout using above code atleast for 1 minute. so it will be like below code,

```
Jsoup.connect("http://example.com").timeout(60000);
```